# Rails 5 - save rolls back because nested models parent model is not being saved before child model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, nested-attributes, nested-form-for

Ok folks, Rails 5 has really had its nuances differing from Rails 4. What I have going on is that every time I click the submit button on the form it reloads with the error **Profile user must exist** and **Profile user can't be blank**. The form loads fine including the nested models form, but for what ever reason it is failing to save the parent model before attempting to save the child model with the following output to the console:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.7.0 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started POST "/users" for 192.168.0.31 at 2017-03-09 18:51:04 -0500
Cannot render console from 192.168.0.31! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JPKO+ppAYqwWS8tWeXhEtbUWynXREu9jYlF0KIlyPgUaabHSzjPZocSxCvr/WEm1r6wAQyT1CvA6hNkZWfPD3Q==", "user"=>{"username"=>"test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_type_id"=>"1", "profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"123", "middle_name"=>"123", "last_name"=>"123", "email"=>"123@123.com", "phone_number"=>"1234567890", "cell_number"=>"1234567890"}}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (112.5ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (118.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 834ms (Views: 780.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

I have have had other problems out of this relationship and I am thinking that maybe I need to rebuild the project. 
Here is all of the relevant code around this issue:

```
###############################################################################
### Users Model
###############################################################################
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
    end

###############################################################################
### Profile Model
###############################################################################
    class Profile < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :profile
      validates_presence_of :user
    end
###############################################################################
### Users Controller
###############################################################################
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /users
      # GET /users.json
      def index
        @users = User.all
      end

      # GET /users/1
      # GET /users/1.json
      def show
        @user.build_profile
      end

      # GET /users/new
      def new
        @user = User.new
        @user.build_profile
      end

      # GET /users/1/edit
      def edit
        @user.build_profile
      end

      # POST /users
      # POST /users.json
      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /users/1
      # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.update(user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /users/1
      # DELETE /users/1.json
      def destroy
        @user.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_user
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :user_type_id, profile_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :cell_number, :email])
        end
    end

###############################################################################
### Form View
###############################################################################
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <% if user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
            <!--<li><%= debug f %></li>-->
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.text_field :password %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <% if params[:trainer] == "true" %>
          <%= f.label :user_type_id %>
          <%= f.text_field :user_type_id, :readonly => true, :value => '2' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= f.label :user_type_id %>
          <%= f.text_field :user_type_id, :readonly => true, :value => '1'  %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
        <h2>Account Profile</h2>
        <%= f.fields_for :profile do |profile| %>
          <%#= profile.inspect %>
            <div>
              <%= profile.label :first_name %>
              <%= profile.text_field :first_name %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= profile.label :middle_name %>
              <%= profile.text_field :middle_name %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= profile.label :last_name %>
              <%= profile.text_field :last_name %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= profile.label :email %>
              <%= profile.text_field :email %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= profile.label :phone_number %>
              <%= profile.telephone_field :phone_number %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= profile.label :cell_phone %>
              <%= profile.telephone_field :cell_number %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
        <%= debug params %>
        <%= debug user %>
        <%= debug user.profile %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: There does not seem to be a solution and since no one is providing help i am going to assume it is a bug. I will put a bounty on this when the system lets me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright I rephrased the question on another question and I finally found the answer to this. So I am pasting my answer from there, in case someone searches for the issue in the same fashion that I was asking the question here.

Ok, I am answering my own question because I know many people are struggling with this and I actually have the answer and not a vague response to the documentation.

First we will just be using a one to one relationship for this example. When you create your relationships you need to make sure that the parent model has the following

1. inverse_of:
2. autosave: true
3. accepts_nested_attributes_for :model, allow_destroy:true

Here is the Users model then I will explain,

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end
```

in Rails 5 you need inverse_of: because this tells Rails that there is a relationship through foreign key and that it needs to be set on the nested model when saving your form data. Now if you were to leave **autosave: true** off from the relationship line you are left with the **user_id** not saving to the profiles table and just the other columns, unless you have validations off and then it won't error out it will just save it without the **user_id**. What is going on here is **autosave: true** is making sure that the user record is saved first so that it has the **user_id** to store in the nested attributes for the **profile** model.
That is it in a nutshell why the **user_id** was not traversing to the child and it was rolling back rather than committing. 
Also one last gotcha is there are some posts out there telling you in your controller for the edit route you should add **@user.build_profile** like I have in my post. DO NOT DO IT THEY ARE DEAD WRONG, after assessing the console output it results in

```
Started GET "/users/1/edit" for 192.168.0.31 at 2017-03-12 22:38:17 -0400
Cannot render console from 192.168.0.31! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `profiles` SET `user_id` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2017-03-13 02:38:17' WHERE `profiles`.`id` = 1
   (59.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (44.8ms)
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (50.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 174ms (Views: 98.6ms | ActiveRecord: 61.1ms)
```

If you look it is rebuilding the profile from scratch and resetting the user_id to null for the record that matches the current user you are editing. So be very careful of this as I have seen tons of posts making this suggestion and it cost me DAYS of research to find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6.1

I had a similar issue that was fixed by removing `validates_presence_of :user` and `validates :user_id, presence: true` from my profile model.  Your model obviously did not have the same validations mine had, but I thought it may be useful to add this answer in case others do.

I did not need to add `inverse_of` or `autosave` to either model to get the nested attributes to save correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I had the same problem but only for my rspec tests. I ended up doing `rails db:reset RAILS_ENV=test` and that solved it. I did not need to add inverse_of: :user or autosave:true to the models.

One theory you could check in a dev or production system is if your seed for the table somehow got off. So then it can't insert the user row because the id is in use and then the profile create fails because the user create failed. In postgresql you could run:  `SELECT setval('users_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM users}));`

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue (did not save with nested attributes).

In the controller, I changed my `@user.build_profile` to `@user.profile.build(params[:profile])` and it solved the issue.

Comment: I will try that shortly, in a way that makes sense. How did you figure this out if I may ask? I have been googling for days!

Comment: Nope that results in **uninitialized constant User::Profile**

Comment: Sorry, there was a typeo. So instead of `@user.profile.build(params[:profile])`, you could use `@user.profiles.build(params[:profile])`.

Got it from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

I know it is not necessarily in the case of a `has_one` <==> `belongs_to` relationship to have a `.profiles` method, which returns all the users' profiles (cuz it's just a has_one) because it is typical for a `has_many` <==> `belongs_to` bond between tables, but somehow it worked.

Comment: Nope now I get uninitialized constant User::Profile